# jQuery : append data attributes when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, attributes

**I want to have these images which are inside span are to be appended  this same span    as children elements when clicking the show-more button below,    I am not sure whether its possible or not   if anyone know   please explain thank you.**

---

```
<span class="comment-text" data-text="<img alt="☺" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png"><img alt="☺" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61a.png">" data-text-short="..." data-text-short-text="See less" data-text-more="See more" style="width: 100%;">
<a class="show-more">See more</a></span>
```

---

Comment: try to post code, so we can know how far you reach

Comment: why do you have html saved as a data attribute?

Comment: @akhilaravind actuallly i dont know is it possible or not also ?

Comment: @madalinivascu its a big app  and this is comment part simileys are generating inside span as data attributes, i have to place them inside span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use append to append the value of the data attribute

```js
$('.show-more').click(function(){

var el = $(this).closest('.comment-text');

el.append(el.attr("data-text"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="comment-text" data-text="<img alt=&quot;☺&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;☺&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61a.png&quot;>"
    data-text-short="..." data-text-short-text="See less" data-text-more="See more" style="width: 100%;"> ...
    <a class="show-more">See more</a>
</span>
```

or

```js
$('.show-more').click(function(){

var el = $(this).closest('.comment-text');

el.html(el.attr("data-text"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="comment-text" data-text="<img alt=&quot;☺&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;☺&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png&quot;><img alt=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;emojioneemoji&quot; src=&quot;https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61a.png&quot;>"
    data-text-short="..." data-text-short-text="See less" data-text-more="See more" style="width: 100%;"> ...
    <a class="show-more">See more</a>
</span>
```

Comment: thanks and is it possible to  load only once  when clicking the see more button

Comment: you use html instead of append, but you will lose the show more link

Comment: i suggest you better go with a toggle hide/show and remove the data attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".show-more").click(function() {
  var container = $(this).closest(".comment-text");
  var datatext = container.attr("data-text")
  container.removeAttr("data-text");
  $(datatext).appendTo(container)
})
```

**demo**

```js
$(".show-more").click(function() {
  var container = $(this).closest(".comment-text");
  var datatext = container.attr("data-text")
  container.removeAttr("data-text");
  $(datatext).appendTo(container)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="comment-text" data-text="<img alt=' ☺ ' class='emojioneemoji ' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png '><img alt='☺ ' class='emojioneemoji ' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png
  '><img alt=' ' class='emojioneemoji ' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png '><img alt=' ' class='emojioneemoji ' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png '><img alt='
  ' class='emojioneemoji ' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png '><img alt=' ' class='emojioneemoji ' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png '><img alt='' class='emojioneemoji' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61a.png '>" data-text-short="..." data-text-short-text="See less" data-text-more="See more" style="width: 100%;">
<a class="show-more">See more</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Append the parent with it's own data-text attribute value when class (.show-more) is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-more').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().append($(this).parent().data('text'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="comment-text" data-text='<img alt="☺" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png"><img alt="☺" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/263a.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61d.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61c.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f61a.png">'
  data-text-short="..." data-text-short-text="See less" data-text-more="See more" style="width: 100%;">
<a class="show-more">See more</a></span>
```